# \nocite-like macro for \footfullcite in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

Is there any macro similar to the behavior of `\nocite`?, in the sense of printing an entry of the bibliography, but for putting the citation verbatim in the footnote, similar to `\footfullcite` but without the footnote superscript somewhere in the slide, and that works on `beamer`.

I want to show some reference in the bottom of a slide, but I don't want to put a reference number in particular in the slide. Instead, I want the reference to be just in the bottom of the slide (as a footnote).

I went through the `biblatex` manual without luck. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by "reference number" you mean the footnote mark, you can define a variant of `\footfullcite` that suppresses the mark:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\footfullcitenomark}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \let\thefootnote\relax
    \let\mkbibfootnote\mkbibfootnotetext}%
  \footfullcite}
```

Here's an example demonstrating two variants - one that only suppresses the mark and another that prints the footnote without any indentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\newrobustcmd*{\footfullcitenomark}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \let\thefootnote\relax
    \let\mkbibfootnote\mkbibfootnotetext}%
  \footfullcite}

% based on default footnote template from beamerinnerthemedefault.sty
\defbeamertemplate*{footnotetext}{default}{%
  %\parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  %\hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}%
  \insertfootnotetext\par}

\newrobustcmd*{\footfullcitenomarkleft}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \setbeamertemplate{footnote}{\usebeamertemplate{footnotetext}}%
    \let\mkbibfootnote\mkbibfootnotetext}%
  \footfullcite}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\vspace*{0.5\textheight}
Filler.\footfullcite{companion}  
Filler.\footfullcitenomark{companion}  
Filler.\footnote{\fullcite{companion}}
Filler.\footfullcitenomarkleft{companion}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes something like that. But that leaves some indentation where the mark was supposed to be in the footnote. Is there a way to flush it to the right? Or should I leave with that space there?

Comment: @cgnieder if I use it as you told me I got the error `Illegal parameter number in definition of \footcitenomark.` But if I change it to `##1` instead, it compiles but it does nothing.

Comment: @adn That space is just the footnote indent. I've added an example to make this clear.